# Metamask wallet lost after Chrome Extension crashed

Tags: metamask

I installed Metamask a long time ago and sent 1 ETH to it for testing last month. Today the Chrome extension crashed and was disabled by Chrome. When I re-enable it, it asks me for my seed phrase which I don't have anymore. I read that creating account again should re-generate the same seed phrase and wallet. But after I did that I got a new account with 0 eth balance.

I had no idea it was this easy to blow away my Ethereum account file... I did not even re-install Metamask or Chrome. Is there anyway for me to recover my previous account? Is the previous account file still encrypted on disk somewhere?

Comment: Metamask will warn you to make a backup of the mnemonic! If you ignored those warnings is your fault. You can follows this indications https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018766351-How-to-use-the-Vault-Decryptor-with-the-MetaMask-Vault-Data, but if chrome has wiped the extension storage I don't think you will find anything.

Comment: I had installed Metamask a long time ago. I don't recall the mnemonic verification back then. I tried salvaging extension data but I don't see a Default folder under User Data.